# Pass function as parameter to put onChange of input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, parameters, components

How do I pass the name of a function and variable as a parameter and then define it in an input in javascript?

My component:
[image]

{this.gerarInput("username","text","Nome","this.handleChange()","this.state.username")}

My Function:

[image]

gerarInput(nome,tipo,fundo,onChange,valor){
return(
<>








</>
)
};

My Error

[image]

Comment: please post you code as text

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, clear details about what is or isn't working as expected, exact steps to reproduce any issues, and actual and expected results. Error messages should also be included as plain text. This should all also be in English.

Answer (score 0):

Pass that as an object instead

```
this.gerarInput({name: "username", 
nome: "nome", 
handleChange: this.handleChange(),
stateName: this.state.username
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are passing a string `this.handleChance()` where you should be passing something like this function(){this.handleChange()) if you want to execute this.gerarInput first, but, if you do not care about the execution order just pass this.handleChange(),

```
this.gerarInput("username", "text", "Nome", function(){this.handleChange()}, "this.state.username")

this.gerarInput("username", "text", "Nome", this.handleChange(), "this.state.username")
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question with the help of the answers ...

When I called the function that created the component I passed:

{this.gerarInput("username","text","Nome",(e)=>this.handleChange(e),this.state.user
name)}

Thanks a lot for the help     ;)